# how to sanitize chars with accents in mysql column name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field where the user can set the name of each column of a mysql table. I use a prepared statement so the SQL Injection part is safe but I have the following situation. My language (italian) is full of words with à,è,ì,ò and ù. They are valid chars while creating the table.

Then I have a second form where I insert data in this newly created table. I get an error if one of the columns name has one of those accented chars.

So I need to find a way to sanitize user input so that those chars are replaced by something safer. What is the right way to do it?

Actually my code is:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-box" id="nome_field" name="nome_field" placeholder="nome del campo" maxlength="255">
//this is where the user fills in the name of the field
```

on the backend I process the data:

```
$nome_field = str_replace('_','-',$_POST['nome_field']); //if user has put _ i replace it with -
$nome_field = str_replace(' ','-',$nome_field); //if there are spaces I put - instead
$nome_field = rtrim($nome_field,'-'); //if there was a space in the end I remove the - that was added
//HERE I NEED TO SANITIZE à è ì ò and ù
```

and finally I insert the data

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO campi (nome,...) VALUES (:nome,...)");
$stmt->bindParam(':nome', $nome_field);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Do you create tables dynamically depending on user inputs? That is something you usually don't do. Why do you create tables dynamically by your application?

Comment: because I am creating an unusual application that will do something usually nobody does. And there are some tables that are created almost on the user input. :-)

Comment: When the characters are valid in naming the table and/or columns, then they shouldn't be problematic being used to access those tables and columns. Please edit your question to include the source code which gives you the error message, include the actual error message you get and for debugging purposes, the SQL query you are trying to send/prepare.

Comment: @Progman my code will generate the insert on the fly depending on the user table. The point is that the field name will be used also as a placeholder in the prepared statement. So if the field name is `città` the placeholder will be `:città` and this will lead to an error in the insert (it will raise an error on the number of indexes that doesn't match the values). Litteraly speaking it is the accent in the placeholder (and I could use preg_replace for it) but I'd prefer to get rid of it since the beginning of the flow

Comment: You can use a named parameter with an index counter. They don't have to match the column they are inserting to. Your query is heavily dynamic anyway, so you could just name them `:param1` to `:param20` (or whatever the current size is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use preg_replace to strip out all the non-ascii characters.

```
$str = preg_replace('/[[:^ascii:]]/', '', $str);
```

There are many options for character sets if you want to support more or less characters, for example:

- alphanumeric (A-Za-z0-9) `alnum`
- alphabetic (A-Za-z) `alpha`

The full list is available [here.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)

Comment: Yes, I considered this option but I'd like to sanitize them like having them replaced by their html entities like è -> `&egrave;` but I don't see how. This code will remove the letter at all and I'd like to avoid it

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). Just be aware of the `;`, as that will close your SQL statement if not handled correctly.

Comment: this is the right way to solve my problem (applying this to the placeholders) but in the end I decided to apply the workaround proopsed by @progman to change the placeholders into something parametrized